# Why ob_get_clean() does not work in body of a function?

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling

I'm using the code below for logging and sending error to my e-mail, but i don't know why `$content` variable does not contain anything when i check my emails. Is this a scope mistake? or I'm doing something wrong?

```
ob_start();
set_error_handler('cs_handler', E_ALL);

//a lot includes and method calls here

function cs_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    $content = ob_get();
    mail(...., 'Error Happend: '.$content);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that you'll need to call `ob_start()` again, after flushing the buffer, if you want multiple errors-per-page to work properly. Could this be the problem? Are you getting one email with content, followed by others without?

Another issue you might be having is that you're calling `mail()` with 2 arguments, when it expects 3 (address, subject, content). You probably want something like:

```
mail('you@example.com', 'Error Happened', $content);
```

Note that the following works as expected:

```
ob_start();
set_error_handler('cs_handler', E_ALL);

echo 'begun';

echo $arr['test']; // This throws a warning, handled by the function below

function cs_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    mail('you@example.com', 'Error Happened', $content);
}
```

Comment: No i just want to get one email and will get one, but without empty $content

Comment: Do you mean you want a single email, containing all the output of the script at the point of the LAST error, or a single email containing the output of the script at the point of the FIRST error, or are you somehow guaranteeing that only one error will ever be thrown by this script?

Comment: Sorry i must be more clear, i want every error and `$content` in my email. (so i may have 3 errors, there's no problem if $content be mailed 3 times, cause this is just a temporary error debugging)

Comment: Yeah, i think i must use `ob_get()` instead of `ob_get_clean()` but anyway `ob_get()` is empty too, i think problem is i cannot call any ob_* inside a function! is this right?

Comment: no its not about my calling of mail() cause i'll get the email, but with this body : `Error Happend: `

Comment: @Aram I have just tested the basic principle of this using `print` and `trigger_error` and it seems to work no problem. Are you sure there is no stray call to to an `ob_*` function that clears the buffer before your error is triggered? And are you sure there is actually something in the output buffer? Try outputting it to the terminal...

Comment: @Aram: try the sample code above; works perfectly for me. Note that you won't get anything about the error in that email, just any output that was previously echo'd or print'd by your script.

Comment: Thank you guys, i think my code are doing something wrong. :D i don't why they never do what i write them for. I think figured out the problem.